# Creating template:

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, css, html

I am trying to create a template using the marketing cloud syntax below:

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="row-main">
            <table class="col col-book">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <custom type ="content" name = "Drop Picture Here"..>
                </td>           
                </tr>       
            </table>
```

When I check the preview, it doesn't seem to acknowledge this content block.

I am sure I am missing something obvious, and will appreciate pointers on this.

**UPDATE**

In my intial code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="cs" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="cs" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
        <title>GiveAway</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style type="text/css">
            -ms-viewport{width:device-width}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,summary{display:block}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1}
audio:not([controls]){display:none}
[hidden]{display:none}
html{font-size:100%;overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}
html,button,input,select,textarea{font-family:sans-serif}
body{margin:0}
a:focus{outline:none}
h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}
h2{font-size:1.5em;margin:.83em 0}
h3{font-size:1.17em;margin:1em 0}
h4{font-size:1em;margin:1.33em 0}
h5{font-size:.83em;margin:1.67em 0}
h6{font-size:.75em;margin:2.33em 0}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
b,strong{font-weight:bold}
blockquote{margin:1px 40px}
dfn{font-style:italic}
mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
p,pre{margin:1em 0}
pre,code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;_font-family:'courier new',monospace;font-size:1em}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}
q{quotes:none}
q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}
small{font-size:75%}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sup{top:-.5em}
sub{bottom:-.25em}
dl,menu,ol,ul{margin:1em 0}
dd{margin:0 0 0 40px}
menu,ol,ul{padding:0 0 0 40px}
nav ul,nav ol{list-style:none;list-style-image:none}
img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}
svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
img,iframe,object,embed{vertical-align:middle}
figure{margin:0}
form{margin:0}
fieldset{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}
button,input,select,textarea{font-size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline;*vertical-align:middle;box-sizing:content-box;outline:none;border-radius:none;box-shadow:none}
button,input{line-height:normal}
button,input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:button;*overflow:visible}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;*height:13px;*width:13px}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;resize:vertical}
label{cursor:default}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
caption{text-align:left;caption-side:top}
th{text-align:left}
/*
 *  Simply fast class
 */
.reset{border:none;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;}
.reset td,.reset th{border:none;background:none;padding:0}
.reset > li,.reset > dt,.reset > dd{margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;font-weight:inherit;float:none;display:inherit;text-align:inherit;width:auto}
.l{float:left;display:inline}
.r{float:right;display:inline}
.cb{clear:both}
.cl{clear:left}
.cr{clear:right}
.cfx{zoom:1;}
.cfx:after,.cfx:before{content:'';display:table;clear:both}
.break{height:1px;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;clear:both;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;display:block;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;width:100%}
.ctx{zoom:1;display:table-cell;}
.ie7 .ctx{display:block}
.ctx:after{clear:both;display:block;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;height:0 !important;line-height:0;font-size:xx-large;content:" x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x "}
.hide,.js .jsHide{display:none}
.out,.js .jsOut{position:absolute;left:-5000px;top:-5000px}
.vhide{position:absolute;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);margin:-1px;padding:0}
.left{text-align:left}
.right{text-align:right}
.center{text-align:center}
.lower{text-transform:lowercase}
.upper{text-transform:uppercase}
.bold{font-weight:bold}
.thin{font-weight:normal}
.italic{font-style:italic}
.normal{font-style:normal}
.top{vertical-align:top}
.middle{vertical-align:middle}
.big{font-size:14px}
.bigger{font-size:18px}
.small{font-size:11px}
.error,.red{color:#c00}
.green{color:#678713}
.grey{color:#999}
.nowrap{white-space:nowrap}
/*
 * Typo
 */
body{font:normal 14px/20px "Source Sans Pro",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif}
h1{font-size:48px;line-height:48px;letter-spacing:-1px;margin:0 0 15px}
p{margin:0 0 1.2em}
a{color:#e96800;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);text-decoration:underline;}
a:hover{color:color $linkHover;text-decoration:none}
:first-child{margin-top:0}
.ie7 a[href] *{cursor:pointer}
/*
 *  Grid
 */
.row,.row-main{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;}
.row:after,.row-main:after,.row:before,.row-main:before{content:'';display:table;clear:both}
.row-main{margin:0 auto;width:870px}
.col{display:inline;float:left;left:100%;position:relative;padding:0}
.col-book{width:40%;margin-left:-100%}
.col-content{width:59%;margin-left:-59%;background:url("../img/bg-content.png");text-align:center}
@media (max-width: 870px){.row-main{width:100%}
}@media (max-width: 600px){.col-book,.col-content{display:block;float:none;left:0;margin-left:0;width:100%}
.col-book{width:200px;margin:0 auto}
}/*
 *  Forms
 */
.inp-text{display:block;border:1px solid #cacaca;padding:5px 15px;color:#555;font-family:"Source Sans Pro",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#777;font-size:24px;line-height:50px;height:50px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:border-color .5s;-moz-transition:border-color .5s;-ms-transition:border-color .5s;-o-transition:border-color .5s;transition:border-color .5s;text-align:center;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,1,1,0.02);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,1,1,0.02);box-shadow:inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,1,1,0.02);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(0,1,1,0.03)),color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03)));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,1,1,0.03) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,1,1,0.03) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,1,1,0.03) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,1,1,0.03) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 100%);background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,1,1,0.03) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 100%);background-color:#fff;}
.inp-text:focus{border-color:#aaa}
.inp-text::-webkit-input-placeholder{font-style:italic}
.inp-text::-moz-placeholder{font-style:italic}
.inp-text:-ms-input-placeholder{font-style:italic}
.inp-text:-moz-placeholder{font-style:italic}
textarea.inp-text{height:152px;min-height:50px;line-height:50px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px}
.inp-fix{position:relative;display:block;padding:0 32px 0 0;}
.inp-fix .inp-text{width:100%;margin:0 -32px 0 0;}
.ie7 .inp-fix .inp-text{margin-top:-1px}
.label{display:none}
@media (max-width: 870px){.inp-text{height:30px;line-height:30px;font-size:16px}
}.btn{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-family:"Source Sans Pro",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;border:none;background:none;color:#b68d00;text-decoration:none;border:1px solid #ef9e00;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;}
.ie7 .btn{display:inline;zoom:1}
.btn span{position:relative;display:block;height:60px;padding:0 10px;font-size:24px;line-height:60px;font-family:$fontSource;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-weight:600;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;border-top:1px solid #ffcd00;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#fa0),color-stop(100%,#f08d00));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fa0 0%,#f08d00 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fa0 0%,#f08d00 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fa0 0%,#f08d00 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fa0 0%,#f08d00 100%);background:linear-gradient(top,#fa0 0%,#f08d00 100%);background-color:#f08d00;}
.btn span em{font-style:normal;text-decoration:underline}
.btn:hover span{background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#faa700),color-stop(100%,#eb8a00));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#faa700 0%,#eb8a00 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#faa700 0%,#eb8a00 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#faa700 0%,#eb8a00 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#faa700 0%,#eb8a00 100%);background:linear-gradient(top,#faa700 0%,#eb8a00 100%);background-color:#eb8a00}
@media (max-width: 870px){.btn span{height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:14px}
}@media (max-width: 600px){.btn span{font-size:12px}
}html{height:100%}
body{position:relative;background:#e3d3b8 url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;color:#333;min-height:100%;}
.ie7 body,.ie8 body{height:100%;background-image:none;overflow:hidden}
@media (max-width: 870px){body{margin:0 10px 10px}
}/*
 *  Base layout
 */
#main .col-book img{width:100%;height:auto;margin-top:38px;vertical-align:top}
#main .col-book a{display:block}
#main .in{padding:50px 40px 90px}
#main .read-this{color:#e96800;font-size:30px;line-height:34px;text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:18px}
#main form .btn{width:100%;margin-bottom:5px}
#main .inp-row{margin-bottom:11px}
#main .secure,#main .legal{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif}
#main .secure{font-size:12px;padding:3px 0 0 30px;margin:20px 0;line-height:30px;background:url("../img/lock.png") 0 0 no-repeat}
#main .legal{margin:0;}
#main .legal a{color:#555}
@media (max-width: 870px){#main .read-this{font-size:22px;line-height:26px}
#main h1{font-size:30px;line-height:30px}
#main .secure,#main .legal,#main .link{font-size:12px;line-height:16px}
}@media (max-width: 600px){#main .read-this{font-size:18px;line-height:22px}
#main h1{font-size:22px;line-height:26px}
}.ie7 .bg-ie,.ie8 .bg-ie{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:-1}         

        </style>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
        <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace('no-js', 'js');</script>
    </head>
    <body class="page-subpage">
        <div id="main">
            <div class="row-main">
                <table class="col col-book">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <custom type="content" name="Drop Picture Here"..>
                    </td>           
                    </tr>
```

After correcting for the space between the "type" and "name" tags, the template renders like this:

[image]

When I try to use this in a template, it doesnt render properly, or allow me to use the area like a template content block:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Content Builder or Classic editor? Each has a different syntax to set a content block

Comment: @Gortonington I am using Classic Editor. There is alot of preceding CSS code and I wondering if this is what might be "Blocking it"?

Comment: if you could provide the CSS, that may help. It could be that the content area is hidden due to the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, it is a simple typo. You need to remove the extra spacings in the HTML attributes.  See below:

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="row-main">
            <table class="col col-book">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <custom type="content" name="Drop Picture Here" >
                </td>           
                </tr>       
            </table>
```

With this change, your content area appears.  If it still does not show up for you, I would look at the CSS to see if that table is being hidden or something.

**EDIT:**

I found the issue with why it is not showing up inside the email edit. (I also must say that there is a lot that is web based inside your email that is far from best practice for email - including a javascript tag.)

If you remove the IF IE statement around your one meta tag it works fine. I honestly don't have a great explanation on why, but it works. See below:

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
```

becomes:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: Thanks for this ..probably saved me another headache but it still isn't rendering. Will add my CSS now

Comment: Correction. It has kinda worked but not achieving the desired template effect. Will update answer shortly.

Comment: I have updated it